# What are the bugs that can be caused in EF by disabling automatic change detection?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I recently tweaked part of my application that was running very slowly by disabling automatic change detection (`Context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false`) before doing a bulk delete, then re-enabling it and saving the changes.

I read a couple different sources explaining that, essentially, whenever I call methods like `.Add()` or `.Remove()` on a DbSet, the `DetectChanges()` is being called, and that can get expensive when we're dealing with lots of entities.  OK.

Now I want to draw attention to these articles in particular:

[Entity Framework Automatic Detect Changes (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556205.aspx)

> An alternative to disabling and re-enabling is to leave automatic detection of changes turned off at all times and either call context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges explicitly or use change tracking proxies diligently. Both of these options are advanced and can easily introduce subtle bugs into your application so use them with care.

[Secrets of Detect Changes:  Part 3](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/03/12/secrets-of-detectchanges-part-3-switching-off-automatic-detectchanges/)

> Don’t turn off automatic DetectChanges unless you really need to; it will just cause you pain.

Perhaps it's in front of me, but assuming that, for instance, I wrapped `.SaveChanges()` in a method that always called `DetectChanges()` first, what bugs could I start encountering that I wouldn't normally?  All the warnings I can see just vaguely suggest that bad things can happen without going into what they are.

Comment: err, nvm. I'm thinking schema changes not element changes. [redacted]

Comment: Migrations are totally irrelevant to my question.  I'm talking about runtime change-tracking that EF uses to decide what SQL commands to issue after you change POCO properties.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Suppose we have the following model of `BankAccount`s and `Deposit`s - a simple one-to-many relationship: `BankAccount` has a collection of `Deposit`s and a `Deposit` belongs to a single `BankAccount`:

```
public class BankAccount
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string Owner { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Deposit> Deposits { get; set; }
}

public class Deposit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }

    public int BankAccountId { get; set; }
    public BankAccount BankAccount { get; set; }
}
```

And a simple database context:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<BankAccount> BankAccounts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Deposit> Deposits { get; set; }
}
```

Mr. John Smith wants to have two accounts at our bank and pays a deposit of 1.000.000 $ to his first account. Our bank's programmer fulfills this task like so:

```
using (var ctx = new MyContext())
{
    var bankAccount123 = new BankAccount
    {
        AccountNumber = 123,
        Owner = "John Smith",
        Deposits = new List<Deposit> { new Deposit { Value = 1000000m } }
    };
    var bankAccount456 = new BankAccount
    {
        AccountNumber = 456,
        Owner = "John Smith"
    };

    ctx.BankAccounts.Add(bankAccount123);
    ctx.BankAccounts.Add(bankAccount456);

    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

And it works like expected:

[image: DetectChanges 1]

One day later, Mr. Smith calls the bank: "I changed my mind. I don't want those two accounts, only one, the one with account number 456, I like this number better. On my account 123 are 1 million dollar. Please move those to account 456 and then delete my account 123!"

Our programmer had heard that deleting is a dangerous thing and decided to copy the database into the test environment and to test first a new routine he writes now in order to follow Mr. Smith's request:

```
using (var ctx = new MyContext())
{
    var bankAccount123 = ctx.BankAccounts.Include(b => b.Deposits)
        .Single(b => b.AccountNumber == 123);
    var bankAccount456 = ctx.BankAccounts
        .Single(b => b.AccountNumber == 456);
    var deposit = bankAccount123.Deposits.Single();

    // here our programmer moves the deposit to account 456 by changing
    // the deposit's account foreign key
    deposit.BankAccountId = bankAccount456.Id;

    // account 123 is now empty and can be deleted safely, he thinks!
    ctx.BankAccounts.Remove(bankAccount123);

    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

He runs the test and it works:

[image: DetectChanges 2]

Before moving the code into production he decides to add a little performance improvement, but - of course - doesn't change the tested logic to move the deposit and to delete the account:

```
using (var ctx = new MyContext())
{
    // he added this well-known line to get better performance!
    ctx.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

    var bankAccount123 = ctx.BankAccounts.Include(b => b.Deposits)
        .Single(b => b.AccountNumber == 123);
    var bankAccount456 = ctx.BankAccounts
        .Single(b => b.AccountNumber == 456);
    var deposit = bankAccount123.Deposits.Single();

    deposit.BankAccountId = bankAccount456.Id;

    ctx.BankAccounts.Remove(bankAccount123);

    // he heard this line would be required when AutoDetectChanges is disabled!
    ctx.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

He runs the code in production before he finishes his daily work.

Next day, Mr. Smith calls the bank: "I need half a million from my account 456!" The clerk at customer service says: "Sorry Sir, but there is no money on your account 456." Mr. Smith: "Ah OK, they haven't moved the money yet. Then, please, take the money from my account 123!" "Sorry Sir, but you don't have an account 123!" Mr. Smith: "WHAT???" Customer service: "I can see all your accounts and deposits in my banking tool and there is nothing on your single account 456:"

[image: DetectChanges 3]

---

What went wrong when our programmer added his little performance improvement and made Mr. Smith a poor man?

The important line that behaves different after setting `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` to `false` is `ctx.BankAccounts.Remove(bankAccount123);`. This line now doesn't call `DetectChanges` internally anymore. The result is that EF doesn't get knowledge about the change of the foreign key `BankAccountId` in the `deposit` entity (which happened before the call to `Remove`).

With enabled change detection `Remove` would have adjusted the whole object graph according to the changed foreign key ("relationship fixup"), i.e. `deposit.BankAccount` would have been set to `bankAccount456`, the `deposit` would have been removed from the `bankAccount123.Deposits` collection and added to the `bankAccount456.Deposits` collection.

Because that didn't happen `Remove` marked the parent `bankAccount123` as `Deleted` and put the `deposit` - that is still a child in the `bankAccount123.Deposits` collection - into state `Deleted` as well. When `SaveChanges` is called both are deleted from the database.

Although this example looks a bit artificial I remember that I had similar "bugs" after disabling change detection in real code that took some time to find and understand. The main problem is that code that works and is tested with change detection possibly doesn't work anymore and needs to be tested again after change detection is disabled even though nothing was changed with that code. And perhaps the code must be modified to make it work correctly again. (In our example the programmer had to add `ctx.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();` *before* the `Remove` line to fix the bug.)

This is one of the possible "*subtle bugs*" the MSDN page is talking about. There are probably many more.

Comment: Really fantastic answer.  While the performance gains can be really amazing I now know why I'll need to be careful.

Comment: @Slauma: Do I understand correct that DetectChanges is checking behind for updates only? In your example it was the line: deposit.BankAccountId = bankAccount456.Id (a property update) which caused this behavior. If I make some changes in a collection of an entity (add or remove) should not have similar behavior, is it? I am planning some bulk operations with nested entities and was wondering

Comment: @Learner: I really don't know if that would be safe when automatic change detection is disabled. `DetectChanges` also checks for changes in collections. For sure it must be called somewhere. You can try to call it only once before `SaveChanges`. Basically if you set `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` to `false` you must test everything carefully.

Comment: @Learner Finally?  I linked it in the question!  :)